# Ruby and JSON: Making accessing objects more tolerant

Tags: ruby, json

I'm dealing with some JSON which is quite "flexible", so in some cases an object might be an array, sometimes it might be a string, and sometimes it might not exist at all. It's also quite deeply nested.

For example, the API call returns a list of results and each result might have zero, one or many thumbnails. I want to return the thumbnail if there is only one, the first one if there are many, or `nil` if there are none.

Is there an easy way to do this with Ruby's JSON library?

At the moment, I'm doing something like this:

```
def get_thumbnail
  if @json['results']
    result = @json['results'].first
    thumbnail = result['thumbnail']
    if thumbnail
      if thumbnail.class == String
        thumbnail
      elsif thumbnail.class == Array
        thumbnail.first
      else
        nil
      end
    else
      nil
    end
  end
end
```

Is there a more tolerant way to access the JSON, other than having to check the presence and type of each 'level' I'm accessing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up using this `dig` method which someone suggested, to get around the `NoMethodFound` errors when chaining hash access:

```
class Hash
  def dig(*path)
    path.inject(self) do |location, key|
      location.respond_to?(:keys) ? location[key] : nil
    end
  end
end

json = JSON.parse('{ "foo": [1, 2, 3, 4] }')

json.dig("foo")              # Gives [1, 2, 3, 4]
json.dig("nonsense", "bar")  # Gives nil
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by forcing things the way you want to operate on them. This way you avoid having to constantly check for the presence of things and can just work with what is there or reasonable defaults.

```
def thumbnail(json)
  thumbnail_record(json).first
end

def thumbnail_record(json)
  Array(first_record(json)['thumbnail'])
end

def first_record(json)
  results(json).first || {}
end

def results(json)
  Array(json['results'])
end
```